# Scroll down until elements are found in Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, scroll, element

So basically i want to make a Facebook script that is going to add all friends from my friends "Friend List", now the problem is we already have a lot of mutual friends (that are shown on the top of the "Friend List"), I want to scroll all the way down until "Add Friend" appears, and once it appears I want the script to click the button and add him everyone else that is not my friend. Now I am pretty new to programming so if you can to explain me more in details how to do this PS: i know that this should be done in Java but can someone explain me how to do this in Python?

Here is the code:

```
root.get(targets_url)        #targets_url is the link of targets friend list
time.sleep(10)

while True:
    element = root.find_element_by_class_name('FriendRequestAdd').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not have to be done in Java, python will work just fine. You do not necessarily have to scroll to where `add friends` appears, you can use the `find_element_by_id` or any other method of finding elements and it will still locate it. But if you truely have your heart set on finding and scrolling to the element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.ui.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(root)     

root.wait(3) #wait for element to visible. implicit wait.

#feel free to change XPATH to CSS_SELECTOR or whatever suits you
friendlist = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'xpath value'))  #explicitly wait for element to appear on the page
root.execute_script("arguments[0].ScrollIntoView;", friendlist)
friendlist.click()
```

> The wait is to ensure that the `add friend` id loads before selenium
>   starts searching for it, assuming it doesn't load with the page
>   immediately. If selenium still doesn't see `add friend` then I would
>   recommend you make use of `expected_condition` and `WebDriverWait` ,
>   altough I very much doubt it will get to this

If an explicit wait does not work, then you should check if that portion of the page exists on an iframe or a different frame

Comment: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Comment: i changed root.sleep() to time.sleep() and root.find_element_by_id('addfriend') to root.find_element_by_class_name('FriendRequestAdd') and now this error pops up once it should scroll down and add friends:

 
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="_42ft _4jy0 FriendRequestAdd addButton hidden_elem _4jy4 _517h _9c6" type="button"> could not be scrolled into view"

Comment: I explained that if you couldn't see it on with an implicit wait then you should try an explicit wait with WebDriverWait. However, I have updated my code to explain what you should do and added new instructions to assist you

Comment: i really appreciate the time but for some reason this still does not work, can you please contact me on Instagram(@dzonny17) or Facebook(Ludwig Vult) so you can explain me more in details if you really want to help, i struggle with this for over a month and still can't find the solution